# What is the meaning of the rice balls ceremony?

Tags: plot-explanation, red-cliff

In the second part of the extended version of the Chinese movie [Red cliff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Cliff_(film)), about 1 hour into the movie, there is a long scene which shows a ceremony with rice balls: what is this ceremony?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok I think I have found it.

It was the [*Dongzhi Festival*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dongzhi_Festival). According to wikipedia:

> The origins of this festival can be traced back to the yin and yang
>   philosophy of balance and harmony in the cosmos [...] Traditionally,
>   the Dongzhi Festival is also a time for the family to get together.
>   **One activity that occurs during these get-togethers (*especially in the
>   southern parts of China* and in Chinese communities overseas) is the
>   making and eating of tangyuan or balls of glutinous rice, which
>   symbolize reunion**. [...] Each family member receives at least one
>   large tangyuan in addition to several small ones.

Bold is mine.

The rice balls are called [Tangyuan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangyuan_(food)):

> For many Chinese families in mainland China as well as overseas,
>   tangyuan is usually eaten together with family. The round shape of the
>   balls and the bowls where they are served, come to symbolise the
>   family togetherness.